# How does DuckDuckGo show icons according to if I've visited a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, browser-history

I noticed when using DuckDuckGo, a tick appears next to a link when I've visited the page, as here:

[image: Search Screenshot]

What particularly intrigues me is that, unlike purple links where the browser applies the `a:visited` pseudoclass, this is a separate element within the DOM:

[image: DOM tree]

I'm aware that browsers [leak information about visited links](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/), and I'm also aware that it's possible for DDG to store which links I follow (though that seems to be against their MO).

Is this a case of the former technique being used?

EDIT: I've also checked my cookies, local & session storage, websql & indexedDB - the page uses none.

Comment: How about opening up the page in incognito window? Does it behave the same?

Comment: No - it doesn't seem to show the tick in incognito, but I made a new browser profile and it *does* happen in that. I wonder if incognito treats browser history differently?

Comment: incognito simply doesn't save any browser history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They just use a styled  element. No fancy techniques. The anchor element contains a ::before element with the check icon (content: "\2611") and the tooltip.

The font color is #fff by default, which makes the element invisible. When you have visited the link the font color is set to gray which makes the element visible:

```
.result__check:visited {
    color: #c3c3c3;
}
```

So it's just standard browser behavior and no tricks.